# Size of pickled numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I want to communicate numpy arrays between rest services implemented in flask. I planned to utilise pickle to serialise the arrays. However, analysing the size of the pickled arrays gave strange results

```
import numpy as np

from keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(sys.getsizeof(x_train))
print(sys.getsizeof(pickle.dumps(x_train)))
print(sys.getsizeof(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x_train))))
print(sys.getsizeof(pickle.dumps(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x_train)))))
```

returned

```
47040128
47040196
128
47040196
```

so pickle increased the size a bit which is I think ok. However, the 128 is totally confusing to me